# No field found for [path] in mapping with types [doc]

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

My ES document model is as follows

```
       "hits": [
          {
             "_source": {
                "variant_group": {
                   "variant_info": [
                      {
                         "name": "Toothpaste",
                         "inventory": 10
                      }
                   ],
                   "type_id": 1365
                }
             },
     ]
```

when I try to execute this query in sorting:

```
         {
     "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": {
           "lang": "groovy",
           "inline": "return doc['variant_group.variant_info'].values.any{ it -> it.inventory > 0 }"
        }
     }
  }
```

following error is raised
**No field found for [variant_group.variant_info] in mapping with types [merchant_variant_group]**

I tried using `containsKey` as follows:

```
 {
 "_script": {
"type": "number",
"order": "desc",
"script": {
   "lang": "groovy",
   "inline": "return doc.containsKey('variant_group.variant_info') ? 1 : 0"
}
 }
  }
```

this script block returns `0` and not `1`

However, if I execute this:

```
 {
 "_script": {
"type": "number",
"order": "desc",
"script": {
   "lang": "groovy",
   "inline": "return doc.containsKey('variant_group.type_id') ? 1 : 0"
}
 }
  }
```

it returns the expected response `1`

Is there a gotcha that I'm missing for collection types or is there some issue with my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "doc['variant_group.variant_info']" you should use "doc['variant_group']['variant_info']" or "doc.variant_group.variant_info". I've also had luck with "_source.variant_group.variant_info".

Comment: Hi, _source.variant_group.variant_info seems to be working. but can't access the keys inside variant_info object.

Comment: I think this is a very weird behaviour

Comment: variant_info refers to an array/list

Comment: You can add ".dump()" after the part you're not sure about to see what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but such pattern worked for me:
I used instead:

```
"inline": "doc['some_array'].values.size()"
```

this:

```
"inline": "doc['some_array.any_field'].size()"
```

Try:

```
{
     "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": {
           "lang": "groovy",
           "inline": "return doc['variant_group.variant_info. inventory'].any{ inv -> inv > 0 }"
        }
     }
  }
```